# Synchronising Lodash and mongoose query in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose, lodash

I am trying to accomplish synchronisation in Mongoose query inside a _.each lodash function like this -

```
            let commentContainer = [];
            let comments = {..} //json object having comments
             _.each(comments, comment => {
                User.findOne({_id: comment.createdBy}).exec()
                .then(function(commentor){
                    var c = {
                        text: comment.text,
                        votes: comment.votes.length,
                        commentor: {
                            name: commentor.name,
                            profilePhoto: commentor.profilePhoto,
                            id: commentor._id

                        }
                    }
                    commentContainer.push(c);
                });
            });
            }
            console.log(commentContainer); //it shows []
```

How can I achieve it, I tried using setTimeout function by giving a delay but it does not seems a valid procedure.

Comment: use promise or async/await

Answer (score 0):

modify your code like this way:

```
let fun = async() => {
  let commentContainer = [];
  let comments = {..} //json object having comments
  await _.each(comments, comment => {
    User.findOne({_id: comment.createdBy}).exec()
    .then(function(commentor){
        var c = {
            text: comment.text,
            votes: comment.votes.length,
            commentor: {
                name: commentor.name,
                profilePhoto: commentor.profilePhoto,
                id: commentor._id

            }
        }
        commentContainer.push(c);
    });
  });
  }
  console.log(commentContainer); //it shows []
}
```

make your function async and use await keywoed when you need to wait for the process to complete before next iteration

Answer (score 0):

It's because Node.js is asynchronous.You should use async/await or promise or callback when you are dealing with non-blocking call like DB-call or Http client call.

```
      let comments = {..} //json object having comments
      console.log(findUSer(comments)); // print result


      async function findUSer(comments){
        let commentContainer = [];
         await _.each(comments, comment => {
            User.findOne({_id: comment.createdBy}).exec()
            .then(function(commentor){
                var c = {
                    text: comment.text,
                    votes: comment.votes.length,
                    commentor: {
                        name: commentor.name,
                        profilePhoto: commentor.profilePhoto,
                        id: commentor._id

                    }
                }
                commentContainer.push(c);
            });
        });
        }
         return commentContainer;
       }
```